# How to use async await in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Tried to make `async`/`await` work in Nuxt, but I don't know why it doesn't work anywhere.

In the `created` hook, it just doesn't wait for the `setTimeout`, and activates the second `console.log()`. In the `methods`, it does not recognize the `this` in addition to the `setTimeout` skipping it.

Can someone give me an example of how it should be spelled correctly for it to work? I'm using Nuxt.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      comprobante: true,
      
    };
  },
  async created() {
    await setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hola");
    }, 1000);
    console.log("adios");
  },

  methods: {
    noSalir: async () => {
      await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("hola");
      }, 1000);
      console.log("adios");

      this.comprobante = !this.comprobante;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` only awaits a `Promise` or an `async` call (which resolves to a `Promise`). When you `await` anything other than a `Promise`, it returns immediately. Since `setTimeout` does not return a `Promise` (it returns a timer ID), the `await` call on that line returns immediately.

To make that `await` actually wait for the `setTimeout` to complete, wrap it in a `Promise`:

```js
async function created() {
  console.log('waiting...')
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hola')
    resolve()
  }, 1000))
  console.log('adios')
}

created()
```

Regarding the wrong `this` in your method, the problem is you've declared it as an arrow function, which captures the outer `this` (`undefined` in an SFC). To ensure the correct `this` context, use a regular function here:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
     // noSalir: async () => {...} ❌ don't use arrow functions here

     async noSalir() {...} ✅
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWbJqRJ)